# Can Telerik Themes be assigned to the BackColor property of elements?

Tags: telerik, themes, transparent, asp.net-3.5

In upgrading/modernizing a legacy ASP.NET project, I need to get rid of a few obsolete Telerik Themes; one of these is the "Transparent" theme (along with "Hay", "Forest" and "Sitefinity"). When I find these themes being referenced, I change them to "Default"

In globally searching the project for "Transparent" I found this:

```
<asp:Table ID="Table5" BorderStyle="None" BackColor="Transparent" BorderWidth="0px" runat="server" Height="100%" Width="100%" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0">
```

Is this "Transparent" referring to the theme of that name, as seen here:

[image]

?

Or is this Transparent a built-in "color" that can be left as-is?

IOW, should I leave the BackColor property set to "Transparent" (and only change *Skin="Transparent"* to *Skin="Default"*) or should I replace this obsolete theme with "Default" even for BackColor assignments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transparent is a valid option for the background-color property. You can leave it as it is, it is not related to the Skin.